# Batch_ Compare two similarly named files and delete the larger, multiple times

Tags: file, batch-file, comparison, filesize, delete-file

I'm looking for a nifty script that will compare file sizes when I feed it multiple files, and then delete the larger file.

I have a set of identical image files in JPG and PNG formats, and I only want to keep the smaller of the two for each individual image. Each image is similarly named, like image-01.jpg and image-01.png are pairs, image-02.jpg and image-02.png are pairs, and so on. Some images exist only as PNG (i.e. image-03.png exists, but image-03.jpg doesn't), and these should not be deleted or compared to "the next image".

Names may vary, but a set is usually quite uniform. Because there are hundreds of files to compare at once, if I had to feed it only two and two images it'd be faster to just compare them all manually, which is what I currently do.

Comment: Are the files all located in the same folder?

Comment: Yes, I indicated that I would drag and drop the file sets to compare.

Comment: You should look into JScript, which can be run from a Windows batch file with a command like this: cscript //B scriptname.js

Comment: Js code could iterate  `// Create system objects
var fs = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");

// Retrieve current directory
var strDirectoryPath = addSlash(shell.CurrentDirectory);

// Iterate on files
var folder = fs.GetFolder(strDirectoryPath);
var files = folder.Files;

for( var it = new Enumerator(files); !it.atEnd(); it.moveNext() )
{
    var file = it.item();
 
 // get the extension
 var ext = fs.GetExtensionName(file.Name);

    if( whatever condition )
    {
        file.Delete(true);
    }
}
`

Comment: That wasn't an answer, just a pointer towards the right direction.  Best of luck!

Comment: @TimH Thanks for the replies. I'm sorry, but I don't know how to code at all. I managed to put together a simple batch file which will compare if filenames fed are equal, and parse them all in a loop. If there's a match, it can pass these on to your script before the next loop. Could you help with js? Code looks terrible in this field. ):

`@echo off|:again|if "%~1" == "" goto done|echo Comparing %~n1 and %~n2...|if not "%~n1" == "%~n2" ( echo Names don't match. ) && goto nomatch|echo Names match! Comparing filesize...|::cscript //B compare.js %~1 %~2|:nomatch|shift|goto again|:done`

Comment: Hmmm... Your batch file won't do what you think it will do.  The script will goto nomatch if the filenames in position %1 and %2 are not **identical**, including the filename extension. You need to only examine the filename before the extension.  Also, you are assuming that "Alpha.JPG" and "Alpha.PNG" will always be right next to each other in the argument list, which might not be true.

Comment: If this is something you will find useful, I'll try to work up a script for you, although this is outside the scope of StackOverflow...  :-)  Might take me a couple days though, since I don't get on here much.

Answer (score 1):

I got some help and added a line to the code I posted in an earlier comment. I also polished the code a bit.

The following code worked for my issue. Just drop files into the code, and ***it will delete the largest file*** whenever two files have equal names. Note that files need to be passed in sorted order for it to work properly. I have no idea of how to write an efficient sorting algorithm for the arguments. This is hardly an issue got my use, though if someone wants to write one for a challenge I'd be more than happy to see it.

```
@echo off

:BEGIN
if "%~2" == "" goto END
echo Comparing %~n1 and %~n2...
if not "%~n1" == "%~n2" ( echo Names don't match. ) && goto NOMATCH
echo Names match! Comparing filesize...
if %~z1 gtr %~z2 (
    ( echo *** Keeping %~2 ^(%~z2 bytes^) *** )
    ( echo *** Deleting %~1 ^(%~z1 bytes^) *** )
    del "%~1".
) else (
    ( echo *** Keeping %~1 ^(%~z1 bytes^) *** )
    ( echo *** Deleting %~2 ^(%~z2 bytes^) *** )
    del "%~2".
)
:NOMATCH
echo.
shift
goto BEGIN
:END
pause
```

Comment: I'm looking to do something very similar in bash (linux) but I have numerous pairs with the same basename in a single folder.